# Project Euler - 67 - I don't know why my code gives a wrong answer

Tags: python

the problem is this https://projecteuler.net/problem=67

I can't understand why this gives a wrong answer- 6580, when it should be 7273.

the idea is to look at the adjacent numbers in the next line
and see which is higher and sum that one. So I'm comparing the number in position j with the one in position j+1.
If they were equal then it would go in the next line and compare the next 3 numbers, but it doesn't run into 2 equal numbers so I removed the code that dealt with that.

data is a list where in each position has a list with each line of the triangle

```
data = open('triangulo.txt', 'r')
data = data.readlines()
j = 0

soma = int(data[0].strip())

for i in range(1,100):
    if int(data[i].strip().split()[j])==int(data[i].strip().split([j+1]):
        print('fodfsf') #this is just to see if there are any numbers equal to each other
    if int(data[i].strip().split()[j])>int(data[i].strip().split()[j+1]):
        soma = soma + int(data[i].strip().split()[j])
    else:
        soma = soma + int(data[i].strip().split()[j+1])
        j = j + 1

        
print(soma)
```

Comment: Your code is giving the wrong answer because it's not doing what you think it's doing. It's that simple. So go look at your code again. Put print statements everywhere you can and have a Pen and paper ready to check to check what you code is doing.

Comment: Side-note: `.strip().split()` is pointless; `split` with no arguments implicitly strips leading and trailing whitespace, so explicitly `strip`ing is slowing your code for no reason. Mind you, so is repeatedly performing the `split` (and `int` conversions) five times per loop instead of performing the splits and type conversion once up front.

Comment: Thanks! wasn't thinking about that

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following triangle.

```
         1
      1     2
   9     1     1
9     1     1     1
```

For this triangle, what would your algorithm think is the maximal path?

You are going to need to find a different approach to solving this, but that's half the fun of Project Euler problems.

Comment: but I thought that we had to start at the top and chose only from the next two adjacent numbers- so it would chose 1-1-99

Comment: @Guitarist your code can look at more than what's adjacent when determining the best path. In the example provided, your code should use 2-2-99.

Comment: @jordanm I guess I interpreted the problem diferently that what it should be.

Comment: @Guitarist I have updated the example for a maximization case. This should better clarify why your algorithm doesn't work.

Comment: @JaredGoguen Thank you for your answer, I was interpreting the problem wrongly, I guess that I was doing right for what I was thinking but, thanks for the clarification!